# Azure AD integration with third party IDP using SAML 2.0

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml-2.0

We want to integrate the third party authentication mechanism as IDP using SAML 2.0 with Azure AD.
Azure AD should act as service provider (SP) and 3rd party authentication mechanism (identity provider) needs to be 2nd factor of authentication

We followed the instructions given on following link, but there is no success
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/direct-federation

When user is trying to login, he is prompted for the first factor Azure AD credentials (which is fine). But once user Azure AD credentials are successfully authenticated, 2nd factor of authentication is not getting triggered

We followed the instructions given on following link, but there is no success
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/direct-federation

We were able to add 3rd party authentication mechanism as an IDP (SAML based), but user is not prompted for 2nd factor of authentication (which should be 3rd party authentication mechanism)